# How to delete Algolia Search in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, delete, algolia-search

Magento ver. 1.9.2.4
/ Algolia Search 1.9.0

I am trying to delete Algolia Search due to a problem with the current Magento version.

(It's not compatible with the current Magento version, causing the error.)

Could you please tell me how to delete it?

Comment: Have you install the Third party extension for this one, right?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for reply.
It was installed by another developer within the company, not a third party.